# How to set compression level while using `tarfile` with LZMA compression?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, lzma, tarfile

Is there a way to set compression level while creating an archive using `tarfile` module in Python for LZMA (`*.xz`) compression?

I am using the following construct and I am wondering if `compresslevel` keyword argument for `tarfile.open` method applies to LZMA compression too?

```
tarfile.open(tar_file_path, 'w:xz', compresslevel=9) as tf:
    ...
```

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) is somewhat unhelpful on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 'compresslevel' is not a option in 'tarfile'.

Using 'lzma' module it is possible.

> The compression settings can be specified either as a preset
>   compression level (with the preset argument), or in detail as a custom
>   filter chain (with the filters argument).
>
> The preset argument (if provided) should be an integer between 0 and 9
>   (inclusive), optionally OR-ed with the constant PRESET_EXTREME. If
>   neither preset nor filters are given, the default behavior is to use
>   PRESET_DEFAULT (preset level 6). Higher presets produce smaller
>   output, but make the compression process slower.

```
import lzma
my_filters = [
    {"id": lzma.FILTER_DELTA, "dist": 5},
    {"id": lzma.FILTER_LZMA2, "preset": 7 | lzma.PRESET_EXTREME},
]
with lzma.open("file.xz", "w", filters=my_filters) as f:
    f.write(b"blah blah blah")
```

Please check [Compression using the LZMA algorithm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html)